# Textview Text Color Inside Listview

Tags: android, listview, colors, textview, android-arrayadapter

I'm writing an application that checks our 'webservice' and returns a 'Managed' or 'Unmanaged' status, I keep a running search history in a listview (until the user clears it), this is all working.

What I'd like to do is, if the status is 'Managed' I'd like the single textview item to be green and if it's 'Unmanaged' I'd like the single item to be red.

```
    //This is the String Array which gets populated later.
    ArrayList<String> _searchHistoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Here is where I override the getView to try to change the color.
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _searchHistoryList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        String _currentStatus = appSettings.getString("current_status", "na");

        int textColor;
        if (_currentStatus.equals("Managed")){
            textColor = R.color.green_text;
        } else {
            textColor = R.color.red_text;
        }
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColor));

        return textView;
    }
};
lvSearchHistory.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

The above code actually turns the entire listview to the color of the last search item. (ex. if the last search results in a 'Managed' result - the entire list of items turns green, rather than just the single item).

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: perhaps I am missing something, but I don't see why _currentStatus would be different for different views.  Seems like it must always return "Managed"

Comment: You are correct sir, I'll need to parse out the managed or unmanaged from the string that I pass to the listview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like the source of your problem is this call:

```
String _currentStatus = appSettings.getString("current_status", "na");
```

There's nothing in this call that indicates which list element you're checking, so it'll always return the same result for each view in the list. You should pass in the position parameter and use that to get the status for the relevant list entry (how you do this depends on how you actually get the status for your list elements, but it shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: You are correct.  It's running through the list and changing all the items, because the sharedpref is 'managed', so all the items are green. I need to evaluate it per item, I'll parse out the string and fix it.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
if (_currentStatus.equals("Managed")){
        textView.setTextColor(0xFF008B45);
    } else {
        textView.setTextColor(0xFFB0171F);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
       int textColor;
    if (_currentStatus.equals("Managed")){
        textColor = R.color.green_text;
     textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColor));
    } else {
        textColor = R.color.red_text;
       textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColor));
    }


    return textView;
```

Comment: How does this fix anything? `getView` is called seperately for each element in the list, moving the `setTextColor` call into the if statement won't change anything.

Comment: Yes getView is called separately for each element in the list.Above code worked for me so,